# Pandas read_csv: convert value 'INFINITE' to numpy.inf

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file of data.  The values are floats, except for infinite values, which are denoted by the string 'INFINITE'.  Such values can occur in any column.

I want to convert the 'INFINITE' string values to numpy.inf

Using the numpy genfromtxt function I can do the following:

```
dataparams={'delimiter':"\t",
            'skip_header':1,
            'names':True,
            'missing_values':'INFINITE',
            'filling_values':np.inf}

data = np.genfromtxt(file,**dataparams)
```

I want to do the same thing with pandas read_csv.

I can convert the 'INFINITE' strings to NaN using na_values='INFINITE' but that isn't what I want.  Pandas documentation indicates that pandas>0.10 supports inf values but I can't figure out how to make the conversion when I read the file.  Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

Comment: I don't think [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) supports this as a param arg you'll have to do this as a post-processing step or define a converter func and pass this to `converters` param

Comment: Or do you prefer to just call `fillna(np.inf)` as a post processing step after passing `na_values='INFINITE'`

Comment: I don't want to map 'INFINITE' to NaN.  It is possible there are missing values in the dataset.  I want to differentiate between infinite values and missing values.

Comment: Then you'll have to call either `replace` or pass a dict mapped to some user defined method to `converters` param for `read_csv`

Comment: This works:

`pd.read_csv(file,sep='\t',header=1).replace('INFINITE',np.inf)`

It may not be very efficient for large files.

I've been trying to do this with the converters param but I can't figure out how to write a converter for all columns.

Comment: With `converters` you have to define a dict for each column and pass a lambda or user defined func, this should perform better but it is more code

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but in [How to wrap a Python text stream to replace strings on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45469808/758174) I solve this with a wrapper to `TextIOBase`.